# How to sent email in array PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm setting up an email notification in my website to notify the user to approve a claim. The email will be send to more than one user which that are allow to approve a claim. The problem is i want to put the email address in the button approve to know who approve the claim.

I already try to put in array but the email only can be send to the first email.

Below is my example code to sent multiple email address

```
do{ 
$to = $Rows_RecQuery1['email'];
$mail->AddAddress($email);
}while($Rows_RecQuery1 = mysqli_fetch_array($RecQuery1));
```

Below is the button i want to put the email

```
<a style="border-style:solid; border-color:#F00; background-color:#F00; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none"
                             href="http://www.crm.icherrycloud.com/report/approval_claim_process_email.php?<?php echo $uid ?>&process=0&claim_id=<?php echo $_GET['claim_id']?>&modified=<?php echo date('Y-m-dH:i:s', strtotime($row_RecEdit['modified']));?>">Cancel</a>

<a style="border-style:solid; border-color:#0CC; background-color:#0CC; color:#FFF;text-decoration:none"     
                          href="http://www.crm.icherrycloud.com/report/approval_claim_process_email.php?<?php echo $uid ?>&$emailprocess=3&claim_id=<?php echo $_GET['claim_id']?>&modified=<?php echo date('Y-m-dH:i:s', strtotime($row_RecEdit['modified'])); ?>">Reject</a>

<a style="border-style:solid; border-color:#00F; background-color:#00F; color:#FFF;text-decoration:none"  
                                 href="http://www.crm.icherrycloud.com/report/approval_claim_process_email.php?<?php echo $uid ?>&$emailprocess=2&claim_id=<?php echo $_GET['claim_id']?>&modified=<?php echo date('Y-m-dH:i:s', strtotime($row_RecEdit['modified'])); ?>">Approve</a>
```

Comment: You could try [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a test script I use. Swiftmailer is installed using a package manager, so I include the autoloader, not the library directly. Also, I left the logging on, in case everything breaks you can check the logs produced.

```
<?php
$hostname = '';
$port     = 465; // or anyhting else that works with your server
$username = '';
$password = '';
$sender = ['test@mail.com' => 'John Doe'];
$receivers = ['test2@mail.com'];

echo date(DATE_RFC2822)."<br/>";
include ('vendor/autoload.php');

// Create the Transport
$transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport($hostname, $port))
    ->setUsername($username)
    ->setPassword($password);

//$transport->setAuthMode('login'); 
//$transport->start();

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

// To use the ArrayLogger
//$logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
//$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

// Or to use the Echo Logger
$logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

// Create a message
$message = (new \Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
    ->setFrom($sender)
    ->setTo($receivers)
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself');

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

So for your case I'd do something like that

```
$Rows_RecQuery1 = mysqli_fetch_array($RecQuery1);
foreach ($Rows_RecQuery1 as $k=>$v) {
    $receivers[] = $v['email'];
}
....rest of the script.....
```

PS: In case the script doesn't works as is, it is morning, no coffee, too lazy to come back in an hour or two :) .

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in the `mysqli_fetch_array()`...it will get the result of the whole query as an array rather that fetch one row at a time as it iterates. so i'm guessing it only iterates once since the condition will fail the second time.

try using `mysqli_fetch_row()` instead...

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_row.asp

Comment: Thanks You so much for time and effort :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with mixed up variables. In AddAdress you have put `$email` variable and in your loop you are fetching `$Rows_RecQuery1['email']`. Just put `$to` instead of `$email` and it should work. I guess you are declaring `$email` variable somewhere and it holds one email adress, that's why is sending only one email.

```
do{ 
  $to = $Rows_RecQuery1['email'];
  $mail->AddAddress($to);
}while($Rows_RecQuery1 = mysqli_fetch_array($RecQuery1));
```

Comment: Thanks You so much for time and effort :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code

1. First you are doing `do..while()` cycle when you should be doing `while()`, because you don't have data available until second cycle at least
2. Then you are fetching array instead of associative array, that's fine if you access data at a desired index not by name.

Try this:

```
while ($contact = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RecQuery1));
{
   $mail->AddAddress($contact['email']);
}
```

Also if you show us your query, we might be able to better help you

Comment: Thanks You so much for time and effort :)

Comment: Sure thing, glad if it helped